# Unity 2d game screen messed up bug

Tags: 2d, unity-game-engine

Can anyone help me with this? i dont know what is happening. but the game screen is totally messed up.. even when played
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by making camera Clear Flags to Skybox